# Androidx BottomNavigationView does not play transition animations accordingly

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomnavigationview

I set up a bottom navigation view with the navigation component. The user navigation between fragments works fine.

The issue is that navigation through the bottom navigation view does not play the animations configured at the navigation component, i.e., while touching the card correctly animates with a slide style, clicking the buttons at bottom navigation view animates with a fade style, overriding the action properties defined in navigation component.

[image: inconsistent animations]

**res/menu/bottom_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
        android:title="@string/bottom_navigation_home_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/schedule_fragment"
        android:title="@string/bottom_navigation_schedule_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_schedule"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

**res/anim/slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

**res/anim/slide_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

**res/anim/slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

**res/anim/slide_out_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

**res/navigation/nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
        android:name="com.sslabs.whatsappcleaner.ui.HomeFragment"
        android:label="home_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_fragment_to_schedule_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/schedule_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@id/home_fragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/schedule_fragment"
        android:name="com.sslabs.whatsappcleaner.ui.ScheduleFragment"
        android:label="schedule_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_schedule">
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**res/layout/fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/home_schedule_card"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
</layout>
```

**res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**com.sslabs.whatsappcleaner.ui.MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        val navController: NavController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigation, navController)
    }
}
```

**com.sslabs.whatsappcleaner.ui.HomeFragment**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: FragmentHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        binding.homeScheduleCard.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToScheduleFragment())
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

> After trying the first attempt, **the default animations still play, instead of the ones specified in the action**. *(fade-in/fade-out)*

Apparently, `action_id` is just used for the `destination`, not the `anims`.

Since the default animation was still playing, I opened the code for `NavigationUI.java`. Which is the following:

```java
public static boolean onNavDestinationSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item,
        @NonNull NavController navController) {
    NavOptions.Builder builder = new NavOptions.Builder()
            .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
            .setEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim)
            .setExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
            .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
            .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
    if ((item.getOrder() & Menu.CATEGORY_SECONDARY) == 0) {
        builder.setPopUpTo(findStartDestination(navController.getGraph()).getId(), false);
    }
    NavOptions options = builder.build();
    try {
        //TODO provide proper API instead of using Exceptions as Control-Flow.
        navController.navigate(item.getItemId(), null, options);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can tell, in the `NavOptions.Builder`, the default `anims` are being set.

**The workaround you used was not satisfactory for me**. So, I took the liberty in creating a `BottomNavigationUI` class that would do the function of the `NavigationUI`, but using custom `anims` when available.

> The difference is in the `onNavDestinationSelected`. Please note that **`NavigationUI` is final, so I couldn't override it.**

**BottomNavigationUI.class**

```java
// don't forget your package

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.IdRes;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.navigation.NavAction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination;
import androidx.navigation.NavGraph;
import androidx.navigation.NavOptions;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Set;

public class BottomNavigationUI {

    private BottomNavigationUI() {
    }

    public static boolean onNavDestinationSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item,
                                                   @NonNull NavController navController) {
        int resId = item.getItemId();

        Bundle args = null;
        NavOptions options;

        NavOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = new NavOptions.Builder()
                .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
                .setEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim)
                .setExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
                .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
                .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
        if ((item.getOrder() & Menu.CATEGORY_SECONDARY) == 0) {
            optionsBuilder.setPopUpTo(findStartDestination(navController.getGraph()).getId(), false);
        }

        final NavAction navAction = navController.getCurrentDestination().getAction(resId);
        if (navAction != null) {
            NavOptions navOptions = navAction.getNavOptions();

            // Note : You can Add *setLaunchSingleTop* and *setPopUpTo* from *navOptions* to *builder*
            if (navOptions.getEnterAnim() != -1) {
                optionsBuilder.setEnterAnim(navOptions.getEnterAnim());
            }
            if (navOptions.getExitAnim() != -1) {
                optionsBuilder.setExitAnim(navOptions.getExitAnim());
            }
            if (navOptions.getPopEnterAnim() != -1) {
                optionsBuilder.setPopEnterAnim(navOptions.getPopEnterAnim());
            }
            if (navOptions.getPopExitAnim() != -1) {
                optionsBuilder.setPopExitAnim(navOptions.getPopExitAnim());
            }

            Bundle navActionArgs = navAction.getDefaultArguments();
            if (navActionArgs != null) {
                args = new Bundle();
                args.putAll(navActionArgs);
            }
        }

        options = optionsBuilder.build();

        try {
            //TODO provide proper API instead of using Exceptions as Control-Flow.
            navController.navigate(resId, args, options);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void setupWithNavController(
            @NonNull final BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView,
            @NonNull final NavController navController) {
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        return onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
                    }
                });
        final WeakReference<BottomNavigationView> weakReference =
                new WeakReference<>(bottomNavigationView);
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(
                new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                                     @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                        BottomNavigationView view = weakReference.get();
                        if (view == null) {
                            navController.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(this);
                            return;
                        }
                        Menu menu = view.getMenu();
                        for (int h = 0, size = menu.size(); h < size; h++) {
                            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(h);
                            if (matchDestination(destination, item.getItemId())) {
                                item.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") /* synthetic access */
    static boolean matchDestination(@NonNull NavDestination destination,
                                    @IdRes int destId) {
        NavDestination currentDestination = destination;
        while (currentDestination.getId() != destId && currentDestination.getParent() != null) {
            currentDestination = currentDestination.getParent();
        }
        return currentDestination.getId() == destId;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") /* synthetic access */
    static boolean matchDestinations(@NonNull NavDestination destination,
                                     @NonNull Set<Integer> destinationIds) {
        NavDestination currentDestination = destination;
        do {
            if (destinationIds.contains(currentDestination.getId())) {
                return true;
            }
            currentDestination = currentDestination.getParent();
        } while (currentDestination != null);
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") /* synthetic access */
    static NavDestination findStartDestination(@NonNull NavGraph graph) {
        NavDestination startDestination = graph;
        while (startDestination instanceof NavGraph) {
            NavGraph parent = (NavGraph) startDestination;
            startDestination = parent.findNode(parent.getStartDestination());
        }
        return startDestination;
    }
}
```

Now, with that, **you need to make some changes**.

**MainActivity** : **After**

```java
BottomNavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController)
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { false }
```

> We will be using `BottomNavigationUI` instead of `NavigationUI` since it will be able to use the custom `anims` instead of just the default ones.

**nav_graph.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navbottomsample.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/schedule_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/schedule_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/home_fragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/schedule_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navbottomsample.ScheduleFragment"
        android:label="ScheduleFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_schedule">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/home_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/home_fragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

> So you don't have to compare the code, the `action_id` is flipped now. You also have **2 actions**, since we will be needing its `action_id`. Now the whole point of the `action_id` swap is that **we need the `action_id` to match the `destination_id`**, also the `fragment_id` and `menu_item_id`.
>
> I also changed the `app:popUpTo`. This will be most reasonable when you try it out yourself. You want both fragments to `popUpTo` the `home_fragment` in the `backStack`. So, once you are at `home_fragment`, you don't want to go any further back. And once you are at `schedule_fragment`, you want to go back to `home_fragment`. **However**, I suggest you use `BottomNavigationUI` or `NavigationUI` as they dynamically specify the `popUpTo` *(this will be most useful when you have more than 2 bottom navigation tabs)*.

I have tried this solution on the project that you shared with me, and it works **flawlessly**. Enjoy :)

---

**Other Solution**

You can set a custom `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` in order to perform what you need *(use custom animations as specified in the xml)*.

Now, in your code *(the one that you shared with me)* you have already created a workaround, which is the following:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.schedule_fragment -> navController.navigate(R.id.home_fragment)
        else -> navController.popBackStack()
    }
    true
}
```

**You can choose to keep that, or do the following (with the updated `nav_graph.xml`)**:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    navController.navigate(it.itemId)
    true
}
```

> But, you should not forget to change the `nav_graph.xml` to the new one.

---

**First Attempt**

Alright, so if you check the [NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI) AndroidDocs, you will notice the following:

1. `setupWithNavController`

   > Sets up a `BottomNavigationView` for use with a `NavController`. **This will call `onNavDestinationSelected(MenuItem, NavController)` when a menu item is selected.** The selected item in the `BottomNavigationView` will automatically be updated when the destination changes.
2. `onNavDestinationSelected`

   > Attempt to navigate to the `NavDestination` associated with the given `MenuItem`. This `MenuItem` should have been added via one of the helper methods in this class. 
   >   **Importantly, it assumes the `menu item id` matches a valid `action id` or `destination id` to be navigated to.**

> The first attempt did not solve the issue. **The default animations still play, instead of the ones specified in the action**.

Comment: Nizar, very tank you for taking a time to try to solve this. I already had read the docs from where I understand that is suficient the menu item id to match the action destination - so much so that the navigation works. Unfortunatelly you suggestion not worked here and the fade animation keep overriding the slide anim. If you have a time, I can share with you a project to dag into. I already have a programmatically solution, but it should work from xml also.

Comment: Yes, if you can, please share with me the project, I am a bit eager to make it work

Comment: Thank you again. In my opinion, using BottomNavigationUI is a bad idea since we are getting ride of androidx further implementations - yet it is a solution :) I've filled an [issue at google bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148020931) and it already has been assigned but with lowest priority. Let's hope they fix the amination override.

Comment: No, you won't be getting rid of `androidx` further implementations. I implemented it exactly like google did. If we can start a discussion chat, I can explain why

Comment: [Let us continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206440/room-for-nizar-and-plinio-santos)

Comment: So, the issue I repported was marked as duplicated of [138665563](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138665563), in here was said that NavigationUI should not allow override the transition animations. Personally, I think that once navigation view is setup to use the navigation component, the transition views animation should behave as described by nav component, but Material Team thinks different

Comment: I agree with you @Plinio.Santos, Once you specify in the XML the animations for the Action, it should take the animations from the action. Otherwise use the default ones. Look, **you can make the BottomNavigationUI  auto generated on Build**. That way it remains updated with the latest NavigationUI.